# What terms can I use to distinguish both online and in-person classes?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to come up with two different words to describe:

- a group of students attending an online course;
- a group of students attending an in-person course.

Is it possible to use something like: "online class" and "in-person class"?

Comment: Perhaps dropping the "in-person" part and letting them remain as "online class" and "class" carries the distinction across.

Comment: The company I work for uses ***on-site*** and ***on-line*** to differentiate between the two types of seminars they offer customers.

Comment: How about [seminar](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/seminar) and [webinar](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/webinar)?

Comment: Your title asks about terms for the classes themselves, your question asks about the group of students taking those classes.  Which is it?

Comment: There are *online, hybrid, and face-to-face (or traditional)* classes.

Comment: @Jim a class is a group of students, right? I know class can have several meanings, but I'm asking specifically about group of students

Comment: That’s what I thought, but all the answers so far have been about the classes themselves, not the students taking them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ***classroom-based*** course and ***web-based*** course to make the distinction.  See [this](http://www.altasimtechnologies.com/training-2/comsol-training/) company's website which lists these two types side-by-side.

The two groups of students could then be described as the classroom-based class and web-based class.

Answer (score 0):

I usually distinguish them as class and e-class. E being electronic which shows it was taken via a means other than physically present in the classroom.

Answer (score 0):

In e-commerce parlance, they have 'e-stores' and 'brick-and-mortar stores'. You could come up with just such a creative way to distinguish between e-classes and regular classes. But 'in-person classes' does fairly describe and look distinct from 'e-classes', so yes, you could go with that. A Google search shows that it's been used quite widely.